# linq - convert nested foreach loop

Tags: linq

Been having issues trying to convert a `foreach` loop to linq:

```
IList<DateTime> dicommentdates = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (DiaryEntry dEnt in DiaryEntries)
{
    if (dEnt.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup)
    {
        foreach (DiaryEntryComment dcom in dEnt.DiaryEntryComments)
        {
            //add all the comments for this year group
            dicommentdates.Add(dcom.DateEntered);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<DateTime> diCommentDates = DiaryEntries.Where(dEnt => dEnt.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup)
                                            .SelectMany(dEnt => dEnt.DiaryEntryComments)
                                            .Select(dCom => dCom.DateEntered)
                                            .ToList();
```

Comment: var commentDate = this.DiaryEntries .Where(de => de.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup) .SelectMany(com => com.DiaryEntryComments) .Select(cd => cd.DateEntered) .DefaultIfEmpty() .Max(); return commentDate;

Yes thanks I ended up modifying it to find the last date. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 IList<DateTime> dicommentdates = DiaryEntries
               .Where( x=> x.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup)
               .SelectMany(x => x.DiaryEntryComments)
               .Select(x => x.DateEntered)
               .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
IList<DateTime> dicommentdates =
    (
        from dEnt in DiaryEntries
        where dEnt.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup
        from dcom in dEnt.DiaryEntryComments
        select dcom.DateEntered
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
dicommentdates.AddRange(
   DiaryEntries.Where(dEnt => dEnt.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup)
   .SelectMany(dEnt => dEnt.DiaryEntryComments)).Select(dcom=> dcom.DateEntered);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest form, I believe, would be:

```
var dates = 
    from entry in DiaryEntries 
    where entry.YearGroup == YearGroup 
    select entry.DiaryEntryComments.DateEntered;
```

Comment: var commentDate = this.DiaryEntries .Where(de => de.EnteredInYearGroup == this.YearGroup) .SelectMany(com => com.DiaryEntryComments) .Select(cd => cd.DateEntered) .DefaultIfEmpty() .Max(); return commentDate;

I was using it to return just the maximum value so ended up with this . thanks.